# warning в preg_match

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть такой код:

```
preg_match("#*;$dep;*#", $temp[3]);
```

$dep это обычное int число, $temp[3] - строка состоящая из ;13;1;2;6;88;

Интерпритатор выдает странный варнинг:

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Квантификатор * требует, чтобы перед ним что-нибудь стояло, вот и говорит, мол, "nothing to repeat at offset 1".